# C/C++-API for information on PCI devices

Tags: c++, c, linux, pci

In my program written for Linux in C++, I would like to display information (including the device hierarchy) about the PCI devices of the system executing the program. Is there a C- or C++-Linux-API for that?

I am looking at /sys/devices and /sys/bus/pci/devices. The information in those directories is quite raw and I would prefer not to implement a second lspci.

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll have to implement a second `lspci`.

Comment: You may of course parse the output from `lspci`.  Try the `popen` function.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking at /sys/devices and /sys/bus/pci/devices

That's exactly where you get your information from. Personally I prefer to fetch such information directly from there. But you might find, that `libudev` suits your needs. However be advised that udev, while being widespread, may not be present on some systems.

Comment: libudev looks nice and it is present on my target system. Do you have a good documentation on how to parse the information in the two /sys directories?

Comment: @magmabyte: sysfs is extensively documented in the Linux kernel source Documentation tree. Readable on the web at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt and https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysfs-rules.txt